# Prevent widget from being rebuilt more than one time at the same time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, mobile

I am trying to create a widget with complex animations on tap actions. To do so, I have different controllers which for example are first animated to a particular value, for example 0.5 on `onTapDown` and then forwarded to 1.0 on onTapUp, but I also wanted to add controller which go to 1.0 completely with a different duration and different logic. If I use just one controller I can check automatically set the state with `AnimatedBuilder` or even by adding a listener on the controller update function which calls `setState`. But I can't do it with multiple controllers as as far as I know, AnimatedBuilder cannot listen to more than one controller and if I added a listener to every controller the setState would be called more than one time on the same frame when multiple controllers are running and I think that would impact performance.

Is there a way to solve this? for example, is there a way to check if the state is already being set in a particular frame and avoid calling set state for that controller, so that the listener on each controller could be something like this?

```
  _controller.addListener((){
  
  if( !stateUpdated (?) ) // I couldn't find something similar to this 
    setState(() {
    });
  });
```

Comment: You can override the `setState()` of your widget and inside that you can put a check if thungs have changed or not and based on that you call `super.setState()`. SO you have better control over rebuild

Comment: Also you can chek the `didUpdateWidget()` Widget class method to see if you can use this also to determine if your widget needs rebuilding

Comment: *"as as far as I know, AnimatedBuilder cannot listen to more than one controller"* - use `Listenable.merge` then, also calling `setState` multiple times us very cheap as it only sets a flag - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1070

Answer (score 0):

As @pskink pointed out, `Listenable.merge` to merge multiple container and create a new `Listenable` which can be passed to the `AnimatedBuilder`'s `animation` parameter.